# How to evaluate Euler-type integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $f(x)=\int_{0}^x e^{-t}t^{-1/2}dt$. If $x \to \infty$, this is the gamma function. But how to compute this integral if $t$ is not $\infty$? Is there any convenient implementation in software such as R?

Comment: How about the incomplete gamma function?

Comment: $t$ is not a free variable and cannot $\to \infty$. Do you mean $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=u^2$
$$I=\int_0^x\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt=2\int_0^{\sqrt x} e^{-u^2}\,du=\sqrt{\pi } \,\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$

This error function does exist in $ R$